# getting syntax error, unexpected T_IDENT in csound trying to use faustcompile

Tags: csound

I'm reading Computer Music Instruments by Victor Lazzarini. I'm attempting to run the first program in Appendix B, Shapes. It seems the program can't find faustcompile. When I run csound -z, it's not there. I'm running Csound on Windows.

Here is more:
(C:\Users\Josh\Anaconda3) C:\Program Files\csound-windows-x64\bin>python C:\csoundcode\shapes.py
0dBFS level = 32768.0
--Csound version 6.11 (double samples) May 11 2018
[commit: eabe0dc]
libsndfile-1.0.29pre1

error: syntax error, unexpected T_IDENT (token "faustcompile") line 10:

ihandle faustcompile <<<
Unexpected untyped word ihandle when expecting a variable
Parsing failed due to invalid input!
Stopping on parser failure

Answer (score 0):

It's bit tricky to inclde faust opcodes in Csound. The installer that gets released doesn't include the faust opcodes. You would need to get your hands dirty and install it yourself, this is relatively easy on linux and machintosh, I realize windows is more of a pain. But here are instuction how to to it

https://github.com/csound/csound/tree/develop/msvc

And reading there it says

`TODO: Faust opcodes, need to investigate`

It's bit sad that it's this diffucult, but that said, Faust is a 3rd party software, a kind of plugin to Csound via `faustcompile`.